# NODE-RED Retrieve XML attributes

Tags: xml, node.js, node-red

I am trying to use NODE-RED to grab an XML document from a HTTP source and parse the document/retrieve a specific attribute that contains a temperature reading.

This is the source XML:

```
<realval="20.235294117647058"status="unacked"href="http://172.16.7.1/obix/config/Drivers/NiagaraNetwork/TrBoard/points/FieldSide_Temp/"is="/obix/def/control:NumericPoint obix:Point"display="20.2 °C {unackedAlarm} @ 16"icon="/ord?module://icons/x16/control/numericPoint.png"unit="obix:units/celsius"xsi:schemaLocation="http://obix.org/ns/schema/1.0 /obix/xsd">
<strname="facets"val="units=u:celsius;°C;(K);+273.15;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf"href="facets/"display="units=°C,precision=1,min=-inf,max=+inf"displayName="Facets"writable="true"></str>
<refname="proxyExt"href="proxyExt/"is="/obix/def/niagaraDriver:NiagaraProxyExt"display="slot:/Software/FieldSide_Temp"displayName="Proxy Ext"icon="/ord?module://icons/x16/control/controlExtension.png"></ref>
<realname="out"val="20.235294117647058"status="unacked"href="out/"is="/obix/def/baja:StatusNumeric"display="20.2 °C {unackedAlarm} @ 16"displayName="Out"icon="/ord?module://icons/x16/statusNumeric.png"unit="obix:units/celsius"> </real>
</real>
```

I am looking to get that '20.235294117647058' from this document into a var that I can return in my NODE-RED function.

The few specific XML parsing examples I can find all do a very manual job of chopping out strings etc rather than taking advantage of an existing XML parser that can read the nodes/attributes from the document.

Comment: That is not a valid XML document - perhaps double check and copy/paste again?  Once you've got a valid XML doc, you might want to check out pixl-xml: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pixl-xml ...its my library of choice for working with XML in node.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a valid XML document being returned by the server then you can pass the message through the XML node and this will parse it into a JSON object that can then be interrogated for any value in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix the formatting of the xml, and using the pixl-xml library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pixl-xml), parsing this and getting the real val is easy:

```
var XML = require('pixl-xml');

var xml_string = '<real val="20.235294117647058" status="unacked" href="http://172.16.7.1/obix/config/Drivers/NiagaraNetwork/TrBoard/points/FieldSide_Temp/" is="/obix/def/control:NumericPoint obix:Point" display="20.2 °C {unackedAlarm} @ 16" icon="/ord?module://icons/x16/control/numericPoint.png" unit="obix:units/celsius" xsi:schemaLocation="http://obix.org/ns/schema/1.0 /obix/xsd"><str name="facets" val="units=u:celsius;°C;(K);+273.15;|precision=i:1|min=d:-inf|max=d:+inf" href="facets/" display="units=°C,precision=1,min=-inf,max=+inf" displayName="Facets" writable="true"></str><ref name="proxyExt" href="proxyExt/"is="/obix/def/niagaraDriver:NiagaraProxyExt" display="slot:/Software/FieldSide_Temp" displayName="Proxy Ext" icon="/ord?module://icons/x16/control/controlExtension.png"></ref><real name="out" val="20.235294117647058" status="unacked" href="out/" is="/obix/def/baja:StatusNumeric" display="20.2 °C {unackedAlarm} @ 16" displayName="Out" icon="/ord?module://icons/x16/statusNumeric.png" unit="obix:units/celsius"> </real></real>';

var doc = XML.parse( xml_string );
console.log( doc.real.val );
```

Comment: You can't use arbitrary npm packages in Node-RED easily. You need to either wrap them in a Node-RED node or include them in settings.js so they are added to the function node's context